# Returning Number of Rows in mySQL Using Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm just starting to learn prepared statements for returning data from mySQL. I'm trying to get a count of rows that are returned when a query runs and display the row count however when I run the following not only does it not return the number of rows but it doesn't show the rest of the html code after the end of the php tag either.

```
  <ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Currently Open: 
<?php require('db/config/mysql_connect.php'); 

$query = "SELECT * from ost_ticket WHERE status_id = 1";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();

    printf($stmt->num_rows);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();


?>
<strong> Tickets</strong> | Opened Today:
<?php



?>
<strong> Tickets </strong>| Closed Today: <strong>### Tickets</strong></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Printf](http://php.net/printf) function is expecting a format string, then the arguments. You have only passed in one argument, so it is likely that the printf function is failing and killing your php.

In your php where you presently have the printf statement, replace it with the following:

```
$numResults = $stmt->num_rows;
```

And down in your html, where you want to display the number of rows, place:

```
<?php print $numResults ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to display the number of rows, you can simply replace your query with this:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) from ost_ticket WHERE status_id = 1";
```

With this query you display the number of rows from the table `ost_ticket`which is the table you're looking for.

Comment: That is a better way of writing the query, thank you but it still will not return a result in my code.

Comment: instead of `printf($stmt->num_rows);` use `echo $stmt->num_rows` or you save the result in a variable like `$rows = $stmt->num_rows` and then you display the result like this: `echo $rows`